# How can I get percentage in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Sample docs after group stage :

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      workhour: 1
    },
    totalChats: 156
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      workhour: 0
    },
    totalChats: 36
  }
]
```

[Sample docs image after applying group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xb8o.png)

Hello! How can I find the percentage of this 2 objects?
The final result should be:

```
[
  {
    "totalChats": 192,
    "workhour0": 19,
    "workhour1": 81
  }
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not post images of code (or errors). Instead, add the code to the question itself as code-formatted text. The example code should preferably be a minimal reproducible example. Also please let us know what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Jorge De La Vega Carrasco : What is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: it worked as you wrote it :) my mongo is above 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have atleast MongoDB version `4.0` to do this, As to bring `{workhour : 1}` to the form `workhour1` you need to concat `workhour` with string `1`, So to convert `1` to string you need to use `$toString` which is only available in >= `4.0`. You need to add these stages after your `$group` stage :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "", // Group without any condition will group all docs
        docs: { $push: { workhour: "$_id.workhour", totalChats: "$totalChats" } // push {workhour :...,totalChats:...} objects to data array
        },
        totalChats: { $sum: "$totalChats" } // Sum-up `totalChats` across all docs
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        totalChats: 1,
        data: {
          $arrayToObject: { // Converts [{k :..., v:...}, {k :..., v:...}] into {k : v, k:v }
            $map: { // Pushing objects {k:...,v:...} to an array
              input: "$docs",
              in: { k: { $concat: [ "workhour", { $toString: "$$this.workhour" } ] }, v: { $multiply: [ { $divide: [ "$$this.totalChats", "$totalChats" ] }, 100 ] } }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    /** Replace root of doc with newly created object */
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ "$data", { totalChats: "$totalChats" } ] } }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ChY2nz-V5Uh)

**Ref :** [aggregation-operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

**Note :** You should be keeping `18.75` as is rather than converting it to `19` & `81.25` to `81` to not create any uncertainity.

Comment: Fantastic, you saved my job haha. Thank you!